# Combining Awk with Curl

Tags: bash, awk, curl

How would I set my `curl` statement so that it puts the value of each `$3` in for the username, and the value of each `$4` for the wallclock information?

#### Some further information

I am trying to take the username and wallclock information and `curl` it into a system admin app on a website. Here is what I have so far

```
~/qacct.monthly | awk '{print $3}''{print $4}'
```

Yields this output: (where `$3` = owner and `$4` = wallclock)

```
    OWNER
WALLCLOCK
===================================================================

adeluca
1610
athardin
1
axelsone
18707336
bfinley
1875
bihe
9918667
brogers
108710282
ckbui
10
ctokheim
2445
dliang
6470745
gaolong
3395364
htrn
1
jchen12
13475380
jdereus
1086617
jiangp
24343174
jinkwang
30733663
johnsonhj
58967432
joneskl
32085365
jongkwki
47160388
jwpark
101601184
keefeh
2
ktan
13484388
litd
2031229
lteng
3882281
luhon
32500508
lvantol
66959
lwen
1272867
mama
4635850
mariettaj
44247412
msscully
64419431
nkumr
6
piersonr
454978875
rhylock
187877
rjconnel
57
root
65
sbonett
2388132
shishen
114025934
tbair
1363490
tnath
9196673
wanj
53041427
wassinkt
376268
wdeng
949336
wpmcdowe
5360475
zeiene
159442263
zhaok
3609429
```

Here is my `curl` statement:

```
curl -d 'cluster=<CLUSTER>&username=<USER>&wallclock=<WALLCLOCK>' \
    'https://www-dev.****.****.edu/****SysAdmin/****sysadmin/clusterusage/rest/update.html';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "qacct.monthly" prints 2 header lines which you don't want:

```
url='https://www-dev...'
cluster=CLUSTER # or whatever
~/qacct.monthly | awk 'NR > 2 {print $3, $4}' | while read owner clock; do
  curl -d "cluster=${cluster}&username=${owner}&wallclock=${clock}" "$url" 
done
```

Comment: works like a charm glenn, thanks I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can make awk execute `curl`. Assuming that the cluster name nd the user and wallclock fields don't contain any shell special character:

```
~/qacct.monthly | awk -v cluster='somename' 'NR > 2 {
    system "curl -d 'cluster=" cluster "&username=" $3 "&wallclock=" $4 "' "
           "'https://www-dev.****.****.edu/****SysAdmin/****sysadmin/clusterusage/rest/update.html'"
}'
```

Alternatively, you can do all the processing in the shell.

```
cluster='somename'
~/qacct.monthly | tail -n +3 |
while read -r header sep owner wallclock rest; do
  curl -d "$cluster&username=$owner&wallclock=$wallclock" \
    'https://www-dev.****.****.edu/****SysAdmin/****sysadmin/clusterusage/rest/update.html'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
~/qacct.monthly | awk '{print "curl -d '\''cluster=<CLUSTER>&username=<"$3">&wallclock=<"$4">'\''  '\''https://www-dev.****.****.edu/****SysAdmin/****sysadmin/clusterusage/rest/update.html'\''"}'
```